# AngularJS How do I access JSON from a directive

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have written the following directive:

```
var gameOdds = function(){
    return {
        template: '{{games["@homeTeam"]}} vs {{games["@awayTeam"]}}',
        scope: {
            games: '@'
        }
    };
};

<div game-odds games="{{games}}">
```

This uses the following JSON data (part of the json is below):

```
{
    @id: "69486",
    @homeTeam: "Home Team",
    @awayTeam: "Away Team",
    otherNormalValues : {
        etc: "normal..."
    }
}
```

I know that the method of selecting these keys preceded with an @ symbol works when put directly into the HTML bound to a controller. But in my directive I cannot select the fields in this `["@field"]` way.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: is `games` an array of objects? Suggest you create a simple demo with real data and controller. Not sure why you have `@` prefix for all your properties

Comment: Games contains the JSON shown. I don't know why the JSON returns @ symbols, it is a third party API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@` symbol on scope transforms whatever you pass to the attribute games into text, and passes it into your directive. If you use the `=` symbol, you can pass a scope variable into the directive.

With `@`, `scope.games` will be a string

With `=`, `scope.games` will be your json object

```
var gameOdds = function(){
    return {
        template: '{{games["@homeTeam"]}} vs {{games["@awayTeam"]}}',
        scope: {
            games: '='
        }
    };
};

<div game-odds games="games">
```

Comment: This is correct, I had games="{{games}}" rather than games="games", which meant it was just dumping the object.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the attribute object notation, `@`, you can use the `=` instead.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)**

*JAVASCRIPT*

```
  .directive('gameOdds', function() {
    return {
      template: '{{games.homeTeam}} vs {{games.awayTeam}}',
      scope: {
        games: '='
      }
    }
  });
```

*HTML*

```
<div game-odds games="games"></div>
```

Update: Sorry for the late reply, as what the accepted answer had mentioned, you can access them with the `[]` notation, if the key starts with special characters in it:

```
  .directive('gameOdds', function() {
    return {
      template: '{{games['@homeTeam']}} vs {{games['@awayTeam']}}',
      scope: {
        games: '='
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem for me. I cannot reference games.awayTeam because it contains an @ symbol. games.awayTeam would return undefined. games["@awayTeam"] returns the team name.

Comment: IT's the same, just replace his template with yours. The key point is to use `=` and pass `games` instead of `{{games}}`. With `@` you are passing text instead of a scope variable

Comment: With = I just receive the actual code representation of the object?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I lost my internet connection earlier, I have updated my answer. But I guess it has already been answered, so I modified this answer as well.